# AddEventListener not fireing dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, code-injection, safari-extension

For a current project I'm injecting javascript to a webpage in the form of a safari plugin.

Everything is working fine and the process is as follows:

- intialize seperate objects
- load the page
- parse the page injecting dom elements when needed
- have an interval of 1000ms to re-parse for live-updates

Now everything works fine, I inject an element with some buttons and they are working fine.

Now the page has some javascript for itself, it has an auto-update function.(live-updates) So once every second there is a poll to a server to fetch new elements to inject.

So new elements are added by the live-update script.

Now my pageparser injects the button elements in the new element created by the live-update script.

The buttons are shown etcetera, but there is a problem with the click eventlistener. It's just not fireing.

Here is part of my code:

```
class ViewManager {
    constructor() {
        this.databasemanager = databasemanager;

        this.injectAddons(this);
        setInterval(this.injectAddons, 1000, this);
    }

    injectAddons(self) {
        var karmaButtonImage = new Image('../img/karma.jpg');

        var post_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post userid');

        for(var i=0; i<post_elements.length; i++) {
            self.createKarmaButton(post_elements[i], self);
        }
    }

    static changeBackgroundByKarma(element, karma) {
        var total_karma = karma.karma_up + karma.karma_down;
        if(total_karma > 0) {
            var karma_up_percentage = (karma.karma_up * 100) / total_karma;
            if(isNaN(karma_up_percentage)) {
                karma_up_percentage = 0;
            }

            if(karma_up_percentage < 50) {
                var normalized = (50 - karma_up_percentage) * 2;
                var a_value = parseFloat(normalized/100);
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + a_value + ')';
            } else {
                var normalized = (karma_up_percentage - 50) * 2;
                var a_value = parseFloat(normalized/100);
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, ' + a_value + ')';
            }
        }
    }

    createKarmaButton(element, self) {
        var user_id = element.getAttribute('data-user');
        var post_id = element.getAttribute('data-postid');

        var post_space = element.getElementsByClassName('postholder_bot');

        var target = post_space[0];

        var fok_es_container = target.getElementsByClassName('fok_es_container');

        if(fok_es_container.length === 0) {
            var enhanced_div = document.createElement('div');
                enhanced_div.className = "fok_es_container";
                enhanced_div.position = 'absolute';
                enhanced_div.style.width = '180px';
                enhanced_div.style.height = '100px';
                enhanced_div.style.cssFloat = "left";

            target.insertBefore(enhanced_div, target.firstChild);

            var injectKarmaButtons = function(hasKarma) {
                if(!hasKarma) {
                    var karma_collector = document.createElement('div');

                    var karma_up_button = document.createElement('div');
                    karma_up_button.position = 'absolute';
                    karma_up_button.style.width = '25px';
                    karma_up_button.style.height = '25px';
                    karma_up_button.style.background = "green";
                    karma_up_button.style.border = "1px solid #000";

                    var karma_down_button = document.createElement('div');
                    karma_down_button.position = 'absolute';
                    karma_down_button.style.width = '25px';
                    karma_down_button.style.height = '25px';
                    karma_down_button.style.background = "red";
                    karma_down_button.style.border = "1px solid #000";

                    karma_collector.appendChild(karma_up_button);
                    karma_collector.appendChild(karma_down_button);

                    karma_up_button.addEventListener("click", self.karmaButtonUpPressed);
                    karma_down_button.addEventListener("click", self.karmaButtonDownPressed);

                    enhanced_div.appendChild(karma_collector);
                }
            };

            databasemanager.getKarma(user_id, function(karma) {
                ViewManager.changeBackgroundByKarma(enhanced_div, karma);
            });
            databasemanager.hasKarma(post_id, injectKarmaButtons);
        }
    }

    karmaButtonUpPressed(e) {
        var user_id = ViewManager.getUserId(e);
        var post_id = ViewManager.getPostId(e);

        var enhanced_div = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

        ViewManager.removeElementAfterClick(e);

        databasemanager.addKarmaUp(user_id, post_id, function(karma) {
            ViewManager.changeBackgroundByKarma(enhanced_div, karma);
        });
    }

    karmaButtonDownPressed(e) {
        var user_id = ViewManager.getUserId(e);
        var post_id = ViewManager.getPostId(e);

        var enhanced_div = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

        ViewManager.removeElementAfterClick(e);

        databasemanager.addKarmaDown(user_id, post_id, function(karma) {
            ViewManager.changeBackgroundByKarma(enhanced_div, karma);
        });
    }

    static getUserId(e) {
        return e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-user');
    }

    static getPostId(e) {
        return e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-postid');;
    }

    static removeElementAfterClick(e) {
        var target = e.target.parentNode;

        e.target.parentNode.remove(target);
    }
}
```

So I'm guessing what the problem is. Could it be the DOM needs a refresh? Because the live-updates come from another domain (the original domain) and my extension runs on localhost.

Is there anybody who encountered this problem before?

edit:
the *self* variable is a reference to the instance of the ViewManager class, it's defined and functioning. The functions karmaButtonUpPressed and karmaButtonDownPressed are available on the object instance.

Comment: I think you need to append all elements into the page before adding the event listeners.

Comment: It is working here(If I ignore `self` context): https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/sas9pbjh/

Comment: ^As I see.  Perhaps then an explicit reference needs to be added to the event listener, eg `main-Function-Chain.karmaButtonDownPressed` ?

Comment: @1 Already tried that, it's also not working
@2 Yeah it's working when I parse a page that is fully loaded. When there are updates happening (new elements created from a polling xhr request -live-updates- to the host, not my code) and I try to apply it on the new elements, the buttons are showing up but the click handler is not firing. @3 I tried making the method static and access it from inside the closure with ViewManager.karmaButtonDownPressed, it's also not firing. Even an anonymous function in the listener is not firing for newly created elements from the live-update.

Comment: @Barry Curious. I presume you're returning an object out of `ViewManager` that points to its methods?  Perhaps we need to see more code?

Comment: @Brain I added the class to the opening post. I'm not returning an object, these are void methods.